# Suddenly started getting 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A few days ago I suddenly started getting `400` errors in my app. It was completely fine before.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

It's really frustrating. I can get the `access_token` just fine but I can't get "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX". I know that URL is correct because I can see the content by loading it on the browser.

```
if(!$code){
     $display = 'page';
     $scope = 'manage_pages';
          $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection

     $oauth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
            . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntop.location.href = \"$oauth_url\";\n</script>";
};

if ($code && $_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']){

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code . "&redirect_uri=" . $my_url;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     $pages_data = $user->data;
}
```

Any help will be VERY appreciated!

Comment: Having similar issue. Did you solve this issue? Are you using the javascript sdk ?

Comment: Same issue here I get 400 exception then when i move cursor in debugger back to first line it works really fine.

Comment: I would migrate my code completely to Facebook SDK